# How does ptrace work in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, debugging, strace, ptrace

The `ptrace` system call allows the parent process to inspect the attached child. For example, in Linux, `strace` (which is implemented with the `ptrace` system call) can inspect the system calls invoked by the child process.

When the attached child process invokes a system call, the ptracing parent process can be notified. But how exactly does that happen? I want to know the technical details behind this mechanism.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html is useful

Comment: @tristan: As far as I understand, the OP wants to know about the mechanisms which enable that to happen, not really about the usage.

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev: thank you. thats exactly what I want. I know how to use ptrace. I wan't to know its internal principle

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> When the attached child process invokes a system call, the ptracing parent process can be notified. But how exactly does that happen?

Parent process calls `ptrace` with `PTRACE_ATTACH`, and his child calls `ptrace` with `PTRACE_TRACEME` option. This pair will connect two processes by filling some fields inside their [`task_struct`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h?v=3.13#L1042) ([kernel/ptrace.c: sys_ptrace](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/ptrace.c?v=3.13#L1036), child will have `PT_PTRACED` flag in `ptrace` field of `struct task_struct`, and pid of ptracer process as parent and in `ptrace_entry` list - [`__ptrace_link`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/ptrace.c?v=3.13#L37); parent will record child's pid in `ptraced` list).

Then strace will call `ptrace` with `PTRACE_SYSCALL` flag to register itself as syscall debugger, setting thread_flag  `TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE` in child process's `struct thread_info` (by something like `set_tsk_thread_flag(child, TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE);`). [`arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h?v=3.13#L67):

```
 67 /*
 68  * thread information flags
 69  * - these are process state flags that various assembly files
 70  *   may need to access   ...*/

 75 #define TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE       0       /* syscall trace active */
 99 #define _TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE      (1 << TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE)
```

On every syscall entry or exit, architecture-specific syscall entry code will check this [`_TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE` flag](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h#L123) (directly in assembler implementation of syscall, for example x86 [`arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S?v=3.13#L499): `jnz syscall_trace_entry` in `ENTRY(system_call)` and similar code in [`syscall_exit_work`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.S?v=3.13#L667)), and if it is set, ptracer will be notified with signal (SIGTRAP) and child will be temporary stopped. This is done usually in [`syscall_trace_enter`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/ptrace.c?v=3.13#L1457) and `syscall_trace_leave` :

```
1457 long syscall_trace_enter(struct pt_regs *regs)

1483         if ((ret || test_thread_flag(TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE)) &&
1484             tracehook_report_syscall_entry(regs))
1485                 ret = -1L;

1507 void syscall_trace_leave(struct pt_regs *regs)

1531         if (step || test_thread_flag(TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE))
1532                 tracehook_report_syscall_exit(regs, step);
```

The `tracehook_report_syscall_*` are actual workers here, they will call `ptrace_report_syscall`. [`include/linux/tracehook.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/tracehook.h?v=3.13#L80):

```
 80 /**
 81  * tracehook_report_syscall_entry - task is about to attempt a system call
 82  * @regs:               user register state of current task
 83  *
 84  * This will be called if %TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE has been set, when the
 85  * current task has just entered the kernel for a system call.
 86  * Full user register state is available here.  Changing the values
 87  * in @regs can affect the system call number and arguments to be tried.
 88  * It is safe to block here, preventing the system call from beginning.
 89  *
 90  * Returns zero normally, or nonzero if the calling arch code should abort
 91  * the system call.  That must prevent normal entry so no system call is
 92  * made.  If @task ever returns to user mode after this, its register state
 93  * is unspecified, but should be something harmless like an %ENOSYS error
 94  * return.  It should preserve enough information so that syscall_rollback()
 95  * can work (see asm-generic/syscall.h).
 96  *
 97  * Called without locks, just after entering kernel mode.
 98  */
 99 static inline __must_check int tracehook_report_syscall_entry(
100         struct pt_regs *regs)
101 {
102         return ptrace_report_syscall(regs);
103 }
104 
105 /**
106  * tracehook_report_syscall_exit - task has just finished a system call
107  * @regs:               user register state of current task
108  * @step:               nonzero if simulating single-step or block-step
109  *
110  * This will be called if %TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE has been set, when the
111  * current task has just finished an attempted system call.  Full
112  * user register state is available here.  It is safe to block here,
113  * preventing signals from being processed.
114  *
115  * If @step is nonzero, this report is also in lieu of the normal
116  * trap that would follow the system call instruction because
117  * user_enable_block_step() or user_enable_single_step() was used.
118  * In this case, %TIF_SYSCALL_TRACE might not be set.
119  *
120  * Called without locks, just before checking for pending signals.
121  */
122 static inline void tracehook_report_syscall_exit(struct pt_regs *regs, int step)
123 {
...
130 
131         ptrace_report_syscall(regs);
132 }
```

And [`ptrace_report_syscall` generates SIGTRAP](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/tracehook.h?v=3.13#L55) for debugger or strace via `ptrace_notify`/`ptrace_do_notify`:

```
 55 /*
 56  * ptrace report for syscall entry and exit looks identical.
 57  */
 58 static inline int ptrace_report_syscall(struct pt_regs *regs)
 59 {
 60         int ptrace = current->ptrace;
 61 
 62         if (!(ptrace & PT_PTRACED))
 63                 return 0;
 64 
 65         ptrace_notify(SIGTRAP | ((ptrace & PT_TRACESYSGOOD) ? 0x80 : 0));
 66 
 67         /*
 68          * this isn't the same as continuing with a signal, but it will do
 69          * for normal use.  strace only continues with a signal if the
 70          * stopping signal is not SIGTRAP.  -brl
 71          */
 72         if (current->exit_code) {
 73                 send_sig(current->exit_code, current, 1);
 74                 current->exit_code = 0;
 75         }
 76 
 77         return fatal_signal_pending(current);
 78 }
```

`ptrace_notify` is implemented in [`kernel/signal.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/signal.c?v=3.13#L1961), it stops the child and pass sig_info to ptracer:

```
1961 static void ptrace_do_notify(int signr, int exit_code, int why)
1962 {
1963         siginfo_t info;
1964 
1965         memset(&info, 0, sizeof info);
1966         info.si_signo = signr;
1967         info.si_code = exit_code;
1968         info.si_pid = task_pid_vnr(current);
1969         info.si_uid = from_kuid_munged(current_user_ns(), current_uid());
1970 
1971         /* Let the debugger run.  */
1972         ptrace_stop(exit_code, why, 1, &info);
1973 }
1974 
1975 void ptrace_notify(int exit_code)
1976 {
1977         BUG_ON((exit_code & (0x7f | ~0xffff)) != SIGTRAP);
1978         if (unlikely(current->task_works))
1979                 task_work_run();
1980 
1981         spin_lock_irq(&current->sighand->siglock);
1982         ptrace_do_notify(SIGTRAP, exit_code, CLD_TRAPPED);
1983         spin_unlock_irq(&current->sighand->siglock);
1984 }
```

`ptrace_stop` is in the same `signal.c` file, line 1839 for 3.13.

Comment: awesome :) this is the exact kind of answer I wanted!

Comment: what is the significance of current->exit_code ? What is it used for? I am currently looking into a scenario where signals are triggered while ptrace is attached to a process. Also what does ptrace_stop() do? I See that it is both setting and clearing the exit_code as a result the signal is not delivered. Please let me know if you would like to post a separate query. Really need your help. Thank you.

Comment: Ptrace_stop is here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/signal.c?v=3.13#L1828 it just changes state of `current` to `TASK_TRACED` (seen as `T` in `ps` and `top`) and also sends the prepared signal to parent/ptracer. As I understand, exit_code field of `struct task_struct` (include sched.h) is used to temporary save signal, to allow ptracer to change or cancel the signal.

Comment: the ptrace syscall uses access_process_vm to read data from other process. However, different process' address space are isolated, how is that achieved?