# Why can waitpid(2) specify a non-child process?

Tags: linux, unix, posix, waitpid

I checked the man page for waitpid, but the ERROR section indicates:

> ECHILD (for  waitpid() or waitid()) The process specified by pid (waitpid()) or idtype and id (waitid()) does not exist or is not a child of the calling process.  (This can hap‐pen for one's own child if the action for SIGCHLD is set to SIG_IGN.  See also the Linux Notes section about threads.)

Why then does calling waitpid on a non-child process after attaching to it with the ptrace system call not produce an ECHILD error?

Other answers state that ptrace and waitpid can wait for non-child processes to exit, but do not explain why.

Comment: This is a OS related question, not really a C question, `waitpid` is a system call. You should probably state which OS (e.g. Linux, Unix, macOS etc) it relates to.

Comment: @JeremyP I changed the tags accordingly

Comment: Linux(Ubuntu) @JeremyP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, *The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6
IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition* states in rationale for `wait`/`waitpid`:

> [...] The WUNTRACED flag is used only in conjunction with job control on
> systems supporting job control. Its name comes from 4.3 BSD and refers
> to the fact that there are two types of stopped processes in that
> implementation: **processes being traced via the ptrace()** debugging
> facility **and** (untraced) **processes stopped by job control signals**. [...]

Alas the specification does not provide the `ptrace` call:

> Since ptrace() is not part of this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 [...]

What I understand from this is that `wait`/`waitpid` provide such possible functionality whose implementation is left to OS designers.
For example this answer may help you to understand what “trick“ is used in Linux kernel: [How does ptrace work in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23928530/how-does-ptrace-work-in-linux).
Thus the `wait`/`waitpid` can be notified of state events from attached processes but those same processes have a preserved parenthood relation.

Linux man page for `ptrace` says:

> `PTRACE_ATTACH`
>
> Attach to the process specified in pid, making it a tracee
> of the calling process.  The tracee is sent a `SIGSTOP`, but
> will not necessarily have stopped by the completion of
> this call; use `waitpid(2)` to wait for the tracee to stop.
> See the "Attaching and detaching" subsection for
> additional information.

Comment: The `ptrace` actually changes the `parent` field in the `task_struct` of the traced process. However, there is also a `real_parent` field that will not be changed by `ptrace`. I speculate that `waitpid` should determine whether to report `ECHILD` error based on the `parent` field.